# How to join two tables without repeating two columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, join, group-by, distinct

I have two tables (T1 / t2) :

```
      T1                         T2
   id | value                 id | value
    1 |  10                    1 |   5
    2 |  10                    2 |  15
    3 |   5                    3 |  15
    4 |  15                    4 |   5
    5 |   5                    5 |  10
```

I select T2 records based on T1 ( If T1 has >= amount of records with the same value ):

```
SELECT t.id t2_id, t.value value
FROM t2 as t
WHERE 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1 WHERE t1.value = t.value) >= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t2 WHERE t2.value = t.value)
```

As expected, this return:

```
   t2_id  |  value
      1   |   5
      4   |   5
      5   |   10
```

The problem is when I'm trying to attach the `t1_id` column without
repeating any id. The order doesn't matters. So basically I'm looking for
this result:

```
  t1_id  | t2_id  |  value
     3   |   1    |   5
     5   |   4    |   5
     1   |   5    |   10
```

Every attempt with JOIN and Group ends with the `t1_id` of the first
record matched for every block of value.

Comment: It is confusing that you are including `t1_id` in your result - what is the rule for which one to include when more than 1 is available?

Comment: @DaveCoast t1_id Just need to share the same value with t2_id, the rest doesn't matters, as long as the t1_id and t2_id never appears more than once.

Comment: In your sample data you are not interested in value 15 because there are 2  of them in t2 but only 1 in t1 and you are only interested in 1 value 10 in t1 because there is only 1 value 10 in t2?

Comment: @P.Salmon The criteria to select `t2_id` with that values is that each value have to be present in **t1** the same amount of times or more than  **t2** that step was solved previously with a subqueries inside the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT T1.ID,T2.ID,T1.VALUE
    -> FROM
    -> (
    -> SELECT * FROM
    -> (
    -> SELECT T2.*,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T2 T21 WHERE T21.VALUE = T2.VALUE) T2OBS,
    -> (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T1 WHERE T1.VALUE = T2.VALUE) T1OBS,
    -> IF(T2.VALUE <> @P,@RN:=1,@RN:=@RN+1) RN,
    -> @P:=T2.VALUE P
    -> FROM (SELECT @RN:=0,@P:=0) RN,T2
    -> ORDER BY T2.VALUE,T2.ID
    -> ) S
    -> WHERE T1OBS >= T2OBS
    -> ) T2
    -> JOIN
    -> (
    -> SELECT T1.*,
    -> IF(T1.VALUE <> @P,@RN:=1,@RN:=@RN+1) RN,
    -> @P:=T1.VALUE P
    -> FROM (SELECT @RN:=0,@P:=0) RN,T1
    -> ORDER BY T1.VALUE,T1.ID
    -> ) T1
    -> ON T1.RN = T2.RN AND T1.VALUE = T2.VALUE
    -> WHERE T1.RN <= T2.T2OBS
    -> ORDER BY T1.VALUE,T1.ID;
+------+------+-------+
| ID   | ID   | VALUE |
+------+------+-------+
|    3 |    1 |     5 |
|    5 |    4 |     5 |
|    1 |    5 |    10 |
+------+------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This is a fast and elegant solution! Exactly what I want. Thank you very much! Awesome.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword DISTINCT is used to eliminate duplicate rows from a query result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ... FROM A JOIN B ON ..
```

Comment: Would you like to expand on your solution with actual code which produces the desired outcomet?

Comment: Yes, but distinct rows. Im trying to never get duplicate in two specific columns. i.e. I can't accept [[1,1],[1,2]] combination (which are distinct rows), Just [1,1] or [1,2] in this little case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way.

```
select t2_s1.id t2_id, t2_s0.value
    from t2 t2_s0 
    join (
      select t2_s3.id, @rowno1 := if(@blk1 = value, @rowno1 + 1, 1) as id_i, @blk1 := value
      from (
        select * 
        from t2 order by value, id
      ) t2_s3
      cross join (
        select @rowno1 := 0, @blk1 := null) t2_s2
        order by value
      ) t2_s1 
    on t2_s0.id = t2_s1.id
    join(  
        select value, t1_s3.id, @rowno2 := if(@blk2 = value, @rowno2 + 1, 1) as id_i, @blk2:= value
        from (
          select * from t1 order by value, id) t1_s3
          cross join (
            select @rowno2 := 0, @blk1 := null
          ) t1_s2
        order by value
      ) t1_s1
      on t2_s1.id_i = t1_s1.id_i 
        and t2_s0.value= t1_s1.value
   where 
    (select count(*) from t1 where t1.value= t2_s0.value) >= (select count(*) from t2 where t2.value= t2_s0.value)
```

> Basically I'm generatin an auto increment id on-the-fly for every block of value in
>   both tables

```
╔═══════════════════╗      ╔═══════════════════╗
║        T1         ║      ║        T2         ║
╠════╦═══════╦══════╣      ╠════╦═══════╦══════╣ 
║ id ║ value ║ id_i ║      ║ id ║ value ║ id_i ║
╠════╬═══════╬══════╣      ╠════╬═══════╬══════╣
║  1 ║    10 ║    1 ║      ║  1 ║     5 ║    1 ║
║  2 ║    10 ║    2 ║      ║  2 ║    15 ║    1 ║
║  3 ║     5 ║    1 ║      ║  3 ║    15 ║    2 ║
║  4 ║    15 ║    1 ║      ║  4 ║     5 ║    2 ║
║  5 ║     5 ║    2 ║      ║  5 ║    10 ║    1 ║
╚════╩═══════╩══════╝      ╚════╩═══════╩══════╝
```

> With the **id_i** generated plus the **value** column I can simulate
>   uniques ids for the One to One relationship

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9e32e/2/0)